# choosing between relaxed and acquire/release memory ordering in atomics

Tags: c, atomic, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

I am implementing a very simple logic. Although, I am having a tough time figuring out the memory ordering to choose.

I have a simple struct like:

```
typedef unsigned int bitmap;
const size_t bits_count = sizeof(bitmap) * 8;

struct Container {
    _Atomic(bitmap) reader_bitmap, writer_bitmap;
    int cs[bits_count];
};
```

`cs[bits_count]` is the main deal here. Multiple producers will add data to it and multiple consumers will get data from it.

To synchronise this, I have 2 bitmaps, `reader_bitmap` and `writer_bitmap`. Both of them are initially `0`. What I basically do is when I want to store a value to the array, I check the bitmap if it contains any unset bit and get that bit's position. Then I set the bit atomically and using this bit position as the index, I store data in `cs[bit_posn]`. Then to tell readers that data is available for reading, the same bit is set in `reader_bitmap`.

When some thread wants to get a value from this array, it will try to unset any one bit at `bit_posn` from `reader_bitmap` and get `cs[bit_posn]` and then it will set the same bit in `writer_bitmap` to tell the produces that this position is vacant for them to write.

Here is the code for the same (minimal reproducible example, I may have missed some edge cases):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define UNSET_BIT(bitmap, n) (bitmap & ~((typeof(bitmap))1 << n))
#define SET_BIT(bitmap, n) (bitmap | ((typeof(bitmap))1 << n))

typedef unsigned int bitmap;
const size_t bits_count = sizeof(bitmap) * 8;

struct Container {
    _Atomic(bitmap) reader_bitmap, writer_bitmap;
    int cs[bits_count];
};

bool store(struct Container *cont, int data) {
    bitmap old_val, new_val;
    int first_unset_bit;

    old_val = atomic_load_explicit(&cont->writer_bitmap, memory_order_relaxed);
    
    do {
        first_unset_bit = __builtin_ffs(~old_val) - 1;

        if (first_unset_bit == -1) return false;

        new_val = SET_BIT(old_val, first_unset_bit);
    } while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                &cont->writer_bitmap,
                &old_val,
                new_val,
                memory_order_relaxed,
                memory_order_relaxed
                ));

    cont->cs[first_unset_bit] = data;

    old_val = atomic_load_explicit(&cont->reader_bitmap, memory_order_relaxed);
    
    do {
        new_val = SET_BIT(old_val, first_unset_bit);
    } while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                &cont->reader_bitmap,
                &old_val,
                new_val,
                memory_order_relaxed,
                memory_order_relaxed
                ));

    return true;
}

int load(struct Container *cont, bool *did_load_fail) {
    bitmap old_val, new_val;
    int first_set_bit;
    int retval;

    *did_load_fail = false;

    old_val = atomic_load_explicit(&cont->reader_bitmap, memory_order_relaxed);

    do {
        first_set_bit = __builtin_ffs(old_val) - 1;

        if (first_set_bit == -1) {
            *did_load_fail = true;
            return -1;
        }

        new_val = UNSET_BIT(old_val, first_set_bit);
    } while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                &cont->reader_bitmap,
                &old_val,
                new_val,
                memory_order_relaxed,
                memory_order_relaxed
                ));

    retval = cont->cs[first_set_bit];

    old_val = atomic_load_explicit(&cont->writer_bitmap, memory_order_relaxed);
    
    do {
        new_val = UNSET_BIT(old_val, first_set_bit);
    } while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                &cont->writer_bitmap,
                &old_val,
                new_val,
                memory_order_relaxed,
                memory_order_relaxed
                ));

    return retval;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to think about memory orderings here but it seems so vague to me. I need help understanding this in actual technical terms understanding what possible cases can actually happen.
I will try to give a general description on what my theory is. It maybe totally nonsense because I am really not sure how all this is actually working behind the scenes which is why I need help.

Let's say I chose to use release ordering everywhere like I did above. In `store()`, first I set the `writer_bitmap`'s bit at `bit_posn` and then I set `reader_bitmap` at `bit_posn`.

Is it possible for some thread to "see" this `bit_posn` *not* set in `writer_bitmap` but set in `reader_bitmap`?

Let's say it was possible (actually want to know if it is or not), and then that thread called `load()`, and `bit_posn` was found set in `reader_bitmap` but that thread was still unaware that same bit is also set in `writer_bitmap`.
It would unset that in `reader_bitmap` and then try to unset the same in `writer_bitmap`. As per this, not knowing about `writer_bitmap` didn't matter as at last it was synchronized anyways.

Another case that I think of is `writer_bitmap` has a bit set but other thread doesn't know about it? (I guess this is not possible and is handled by atomics).

I know the question is pretty long. If it's unclear anywhere, please ask in the comments.

Comment: Very minor note, you probably meant to use `~oldval` rather than `!oldval` in `store()`. Also don't forget memory ordering re: `cont->cs`.

Comment: I also noticed that you're testing the result of `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit` the wrong way around (it returns false when the compare fails). Also you can move the initial loads out of the loops (since `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit` reloads the value).

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @Hasturkun, updated the code. Also,  what do you mean by `Also don't forget memory ordering re: cont->cs`?

Comment: Relaxed memory ordering doesn't imply any synchronization (for anything other than the atomic variable being modified). I was looking at your question rather late, so might have analyzed it incorrectly (especially since there's a data dependency), but I wasn't  sure your data in `cont->cs` is guaranteed to be fresh without a trailing release in `store` and a leading acquire in `load` (i.e. last and first calls to `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit` in `store` and `load` respectively).

Comment: @Hasturkun, understanding a little. Do you mean `cont->cs[first_unset_bit] = data;` could be initialized before the first CAS sets the `writer_bitmap`?

Comment: I am uncertain about some concepts here. Ideally, only after a bit is set in `writer_bitmap`, `cont->cs[first_unset_bit] = data;` will execute and this is supposed to happen in the same thread and till what I understand `writer_bitmap` just allows a thread to enter the critical section & set a particular index in `cont->cs`. Does `cont->cs` even depend on `writer_bitmap` in terms of memory ordering?

Comment: I mean that `load` could end up reading an old or cached version of `cont->cs[first_set_bit]` if the contents of `reader_bitmap` end up visible before the change to `cs`. I don't think `cont->cs` depends on `writer_bitmap` at all (which is why I suggested acq/rel on the `reader_bitmap`).

Comment: @Hasturkun, Okay now I get it. I was confusing myself with this memory ordering concept within a single thread. Now it seems clear. Thanks!

Comment: Relaxed ops on atomic obj X can be reordered w/ any ops on Y. Ops on one obj are never reordered. IOW if you have exactly 1 shared mutable obj in your MT program, you can always get away w/ only using relaxed.

Comment: @curiousguy, yes I understand that now. It was too much to take in when I was reading this for the first time, so got confused. Thanks.

Comment: @Mihir I think there is *not* one person who grasped a complete - or even grossly adequate - picture of MT and atomics semantics on 1st reading.